# how do I get my paint program to contenue after user inputs wall info in python 3.4

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x

Im writing a paint program that's supposed to determine the cost of painting the walls of a shed with a rectangular floor. Im supposed to assume the shed has no windows and that the paint cost is $40 per gallon. One gallon covers 300 square feet. Im suppose to prompt the user to enter the dimensions of the shed. Im also supposed to use a function named paint_cost that takes the users input as arguments and returns the cost of painting the walls of the shed. Finally I have to express the cost in currency format.

I can get up to the point to were the user enters the dimensions but after they enter them and hit enter it goes to the >>> Im trying to figure out what ive done wrong here and how to fix it to run correctly.

```
def main():

    wall1 = float(input('enter length of wall 1: '))
    wall2 = float(input('enter length of wall 2: '))
    wall3 = float(input('enter length of wall 3: '))
    wall4 = float(input('enter length of wall 4: '))
    wall_height = float(input('enter height of walls: '))
    combine_walls1 = wall1 + wall2 
    combine_walls2 = wall3 + wall4


def paint_cost(combine_walls1, combine_walls2):
    combined_walls = combine_walls1 + combine_walls2
    Square_foot = combined_walls * wall_height
    gallon = Square_foot / 300
    cost = gallon * 40

    print('total: $', format(paint_cost, ' ,.2f'))



main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `paint_cost` is not called.
2. `paint_cost` should receive `wall_height`.
3. Print `cost` instead of `paint_cost` in `paint_cost`.

---

```
def main():
    wall1 = float(input('enter length of wall 1: '))
    wall2 = float(input('enter length of wall 2: '))
    wall3 = float(input('enter length of wall 3: '))
    wall4 = float(input('enter length of wall 4: '))
    wall_height = float(input('enter height of walls: '))
    combine_walls1 = wall1 + wall2 
    combine_walls2 = wall3 + wall4
    paint_cost(combine_walls1, combine_walls2, wall_height)  # 1 + 2


def paint_cost(combine_walls1, combine_walls2, wall_height):  # 2
    combined_walls = combine_walls1 + combine_walls2
    Square_foot = combined_walls * wall_height
    gallon = Square_foot / 300
    cost = gallon * 40
    print('total: $', format(cost, ' ,.2f'))  # 3

main()
```

Comment: so I really wasn't that far off huh

Comment: Thank you for your help Im glad to know theres good people like yourself out there willing to help others